# How to add ajax load more button on archive page with a dropdown filter + a search bar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'd like to add an ajax load more button to load more posts on an archive page.
I have an archive page that displays all the news posts. We can filter the results with a categories dropdown and a search bar.
Everything is working fine on that side.

In order to do that, I used a tutorial https://itsmereal.com/simple-ajax-filter-search-for-wordpress/ and adapted it for my case.

I created a shortcode in functions.php:

```php
// shortcode for news filter
function my_ajax_filter_search_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_ajax_filter_search', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/filter-js.js', array(), '1.0', true );
  wp_localize_script( 'my_ajax_filter_search', 'ajax_url', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') );
}


function my_ajax_filter_search_shortcode() {
  my_ajax_filter_search_scripts(); 

  ob_start(); ?>

  <div id="my-ajax-filter-search" class="container">
      <form action="" method="get">
        <div class="cat-filter">
          <label for="categoryfilter"><?php _e("Filter by category", ''); ?></label>
          <div class="select-wrap cat[]-wrap">
            <div class="select-style ">
              <?php
                    if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'news-category', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 
                      echo '<select name="catNews" id="catNews"><option value="">Select a category</option>';
                      foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                        echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                      endforeach;
                      echo '</select>';
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search-filter">
              <label for="search"><?php _e("Search", ''); ?></label>
              <div class="search-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="<?php _e('Search...', ''); ?>">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-orange" name="submit">
                  <span class="search-svg"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
      </form>
      <div id="ajax_fitler_search_results"></div>
  </div>
   
  <?php
  return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode ('my_ajax_filter_search', 'my_ajax_filter_search_shortcode');
```

```php
// Ajax Callback
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_filter_search', 'my_ajax_filter_search_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_filter_search', 'my_ajax_filter_search_callback');
 
function my_ajax_filter_search_callback() {
 
    header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
  
    $tax_query = array();
 
    if(isset($_GET['catNews'])) {
        $newsCat = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['catNews'] );
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news-category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $newsCat
        );
    }
 
    $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'plaidoyer',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query
    );
 
    if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
        $search = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['search'] );
        $search_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'news',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => $tax_query,
            's' => $search
        ) );
    } else {
        $search_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    }
    
    if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
      $result = array();
      
      while ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
        $search_query->the_post();
        
            $cleanedSubstr = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 60, '...' );
            $term_obj_list = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'news-category' );
            $cats = join(' • ', wp_list_pluck($term_obj_list, 'name'));

            $result[] = array(
                "id" => get_the_ID(),
                "title" => get_the_title(),
                "content" => $cleanedSubstr,
                "permalink" => get_permalink(),
                "date" => get_the_date(),
                "catNews" => $cats,
                "featureImg" => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'medium_large')
            );
        }
        wp_reset_query();
 
        echo json_encode($result);
 
    } else {
      ob_clean();
      echo json_encode("No data.");
      ob_flush();
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

And finally, the jQuery ajax function in filter-js.js file :

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mafs = $("#my-ajax-filter-search"); 
        var mafsForm = mafs.find("form"); 
        
        mafsForm.on('change', function() {
            submitForm();
        });
        mafsForm.keypress(function() {
            submitForm();
        });
        mafsForm.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
        

        function submitForm() {

            if(mafsForm.find("#search").val().length !== 0) {
                var search = mafsForm.find("#search").val();
            }
            if(mafsForm.find("#catNews").val().length !== 0) {
                var catNews = mafsForm.find("#catNews").val();
            }
                
            var data = {
                action : "my_ajax_filter_search",
                search : search,
                catNews : catNews
            }
            
            $.ajax({
                url : ajax_url,
                data : data,
                success : function(response) {
                    mafs.find("div#ajax_fitler_search_results").empty();
                    if(response !== "No data.") {
                        for(var i = 0 ;  i < response.length ; i++) {
                            var html  = "<div class='news-component'>";
                            html += "       <div class='list-item news-list-item'>";
                            html += "           <a class='news-link' href='" + response[i].permalink + "' title='More'>";
                            html += "               <div class='news-content'>";
                            html += "                   <div class='inner-content'>";
                            html += "                       <div class='image-wrapper'>";
                            html += "                           <div class='image-news' style=\"background-image: url('" + response[i].featureImg + "');\"></div>";
                            html += "                       </div>";
                            html += "                       <div class='content-wrapper'>";
                            html += "                           <div>";
                            html += "                               <span class='title'>" + response[i].title + "</span>";
                            html += "                               <span class='date'>" + response[i].date + "</span>";
                            html += "                               <span class='news-cats'>" + response[i].catNews + "</span>";
                            html += "                           </div>";
                            html += "                           <p>" + response[i].content + "</p>";
                            html += "                       </div>";
                            html += "                   </div>";
                            html += "               </div>";
                            html += "               <button class='btn news-btn btn-orange' type='button'> &gt; More</button>";
                            html += "           </a>";
                            html += "      </div>";
                            html += "  </div>";
                            mafs.find("div#ajax_fitler_search_results").append(html);
                        }
                    } else {
                        var html  = "<div class='no-result'>No results found for your search criteria</div>";
                        mafs.find("div#ajax_fitler_search_results").append(html);
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                    console.log('Exception:', exception);
                }
            });
        };
        mafsForm.trigger('change');
    });

})( jQuery );
```

I'm kind of "stuck" here right now, I think using an offset (like 5 posts to load) to call other posts after the last 5 displayed can be a solution but I don't really know if it's a good way and I'm not sure how to do that.